# How to document.create a script then use it immediately

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

http://jsbin.com/iwuhum/1/

I'm trying to add a script element, which has `var myVar = "hello world"`, and immediately after, I want to use `myVar`.  Unfortunately, `typeof myVar` is `undefined`, unless I do a `setTimeout` of more than `0`.  `setTimeout` of `0` does not work. I copied Google Analytic's way of creating the script element, and they seem to have it working just fine. Am I missing something?

**Note:** for some reason, jsbin is not behaving the same as if you were to copy/paste this code into a .html file and try it locally. I suppose jsbin already has a delay, which makes the `setTimeout` of `0` work.

```
(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.defer = false;
    ga.src = 'http://bakersdozen13.lfchosting.com/test.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})(); // note: the () executes it immediately (or it should!)

$("#out").append('typeof myVar is ' + typeof myVar); // "undefined" :(

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#out").append('<br/>typeof myVar is ' + typeof myVar); // "undefined" :(
}, 0);    

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#out").append('<br/>typeof myVar is ' + typeof myVar); // "string"
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script file has to load. There is no way to wait for it to load. Since it looks like you are using jQuery, utilize getScript()

```
$.getScript("http://bakersdozen13.lfchosting.com/test.js", function() { 
    alert(myVar);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9e82/)

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought the issue here is that the script has not loaded at the point you first call the typeof.

You would be best to use the `onload`, or something similar like jquery `ready`, event to fire callbacks for when your script has loaded.

```
 ga.onload = function(){
        $("#out").append('typeof myVar is ' + typeof myVar);
    }
```

**In response to comments**, something like the following should work but is a bad idea:

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
//The false at the end makes the request sychronous
xhReq.open("GET", "http://bakersdozen13.lfchosting.com/test.js", false);
xhReq.send(null);
// I know eval is evil, but this is just a demonstration. This won't happen until the page is loaded.
eval(xhReq.responseText);
// Assuming myVar is a global variable initialized within the script this should now work
$("#out").append('typeof myVar is ' + typeof myVar);
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: To add a little: jQuery's `ready` event is implemented on the `onreadystatechange` event. It fires separately from `onload`. My guess is that they fire right after each-other in this case so there is no real winner. `onload` usually waits for other resources (like images and scripts), but that's not relevant here.

Comment: thanks for ur response. unfortunately that means the ga.onload would have to be inside of the `(function(){...})();`. I'd like to have it as its own block of code, so I can put it later in a `loadScript` function, for example, and call it as I need to.

Comment: There are many ways to restructure this. I would probably change your immediate function to a normal function that takes the callback as a parameter. Then you could put the onload inside that function and have it run the callback.

Comment: for both answers, it's looking like there's no way to avoid having a callback function.

Comment: Javascript is an event driven language so no there isn't really any alternative. The fact is that it takes time to load a file so you have to wait for that to finish. I suppose you could do a synchronous rather than an asynchronous request using the xmlhttprequest object but this would make your code hang while the script page is loaded. This is generally bad practice.